# How to start a script/app in node.js?

Tags: windows, node.js

If I type `console.log('Hello World');` in node.js it works, I get the "Hello World" message back.

But if I make a "helloworld.js" document with `console.log('Hello World');` inside and then type "node helloworld.js" in node then nothing happens.

I have tried placing the script in same folder as node.js but still doesn't work.

Comment: Do you get any output at all? What OS are you using? How is Node installed?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you're not running `Nodejs.exe` because that is the [REPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop).

Instead you should open a regular Command Prompt window (`cmd.exe`) and run the command

`node helloworld.js`

Make sure you run this command in the directory where the js file exists, the node application  path is mapped in your environment settings.

Comment: Thanks, I was doing it in nodejs.exe :) A side question I need answer to to be able to start the script still.. How do i navigate in cmd? The only command I know of is "cd.." I have no idea to navigate to the directory the script is in. I never really had to use cmd until now.

Comment: @Krymmt The easiest way would be to create a folder for example in your C drive root `C:\nodeApp` then you would enter in command prompt : `cd C:\nodeApp` enter , then `node helloworld.js`